# Apache 2.4 + php-fpm - AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n' mod_proxy_balancer

Tags: php, mod-proxy, apache2.4, mod-proxy-balancer

I'm configuring an Apache 2.4.9 with php-fpm 5.5.9 in my Ubuntu 14.04. What I want is to make a balancer for the php-fpm requests but It throws the following error:

`AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'`

When I try to access my php file. It seems that proxy balancer doesn't grab the document root passed by ProxyPassMatch to it. I'm using UDS to make apache access the php-fpm sockets instead of using network tcp.

If I configure it without balancer, everything works fine.

## WORKS

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock1|fcgi://./var/www/html
```

## NOT WORKS

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ balancer://localhost/var/www/html
<Proxy balancer://localhost/>
    BalancerMember unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock1|fcgi://localhost:9001
    BalancerMember unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock2|fcgi://localhost:9002
    BalancerMember unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock3|fcgi://localhost:9003
    BalancerMember unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock4|fcgi://localhost:9004
</Proxy>
```

This is the balancer's config log:

```
[Sun Jun 15 12:32:30.839726 2014] [authz_core:debug] [pid 12217:tid 140330025703168] mod_authz_core.c(828): [client 10.1.1.2:52526] AH01628: authorization result: granted (no directives)
[Sun Jun 15 12:32:30.839899 2014] [lbmethod_byrequests:debug] [pid 12217:tid 140330025703168] mod_lbmethod_byrequests.c(97): AH01207: proxy: Entering byrequests for BALANCER (balancer://localhost)
[Sun Jun 15 12:32:30.839915 2014] [lbmethod_byrequests:debug] [pid 12217:tid 140330025703168] mod_lbmethod_byrequests.c(144): AH01208: proxy: byrequests selected worker "fcgi://localhost:9001" : busy 0 : lbstatus -3
[Sun Jun 15 12:32:30.839929 2014] [proxy_balancer:debug] [pid 12217:tid 140330025703168] mod_proxy_balancer.c(616): [client 10.1.1.2:52526] AH01172: balancer://localhost: worker (fcgi://localhost:9001) rewritten to fcgi://localhost:9001/var/www/html/info.php
[Sun Jun 15 12:32:30.839942 2014] [proxy:debug] [pid 12217:tid 140330025703168] proxy_util.c(1761): AH00924: worker unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock1|fcgi://localhost:9001 shared already initialized
[Sun Jun 15 12:32:30.839958 2014] [proxy:debug] [pid 12217:tid 140330025703168] proxy_util.c(1808): AH00927: initializing worker unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock1|fcgi://localhost:9001 local
[Sun Jun 15 12:32:30.840004 2014] [proxy:debug] [pid 12217:tid 140330025703168] proxy_util.c(1843): AH00930: initialized pool in child 12217 for (localhost) min=0 max=25 smax=25
[Sun Jun 15 12:32:30.840018 2014] [proxy:debug] [pid 12217:tid 140330025703168] mod_proxy.c(1138): [client 10.1.1.2:52526] AH01143: Running scheme balancer handler (attempt 0)
[Sun Jun 15 12:32:30.840039 2014] [proxy_fcgi:debug] [pid 12217:tid 140330025703168] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(768): [client 10.1.1.2:52526] AH01076: url: fcgi://localhost:9001/var/www/html/info.php proxyname: (null) proxyport: 0
[Sun Jun 15 12:32:30.840058 2014] [proxy_fcgi:debug] [pid 12217:tid 140330025703168] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(775): [client 10.1.1.2:52526] AH01078: serving URL fcgi://localhost:9001/var/www/html/info.php
[Sun Jun 15 12:32:30.840090 2014] [proxy:debug] [pid 12217:tid 140330025703168] proxy_util.c(2094): AH00942: FCGI: has acquired connection for (localhost)
[Sun Jun 15 12:32:30.840102 2014] [proxy:debug] [pid 12217:tid 140330025703168] proxy_util.c(2108): AH02545: FCGI: has determined UDS as /var/run/php5-fpm.sock1
[Sun Jun 15 12:32:30.840115 2014] [proxy:debug] [pid 12217:tid 140330025703168] proxy_util.c(2169): [client 10.1.1.2:52526] AH00944: connecting fcgi://localhost:9001/var/www/html/info.php to localhost:9001
[Sun Jun 15 12:32:30.840134 2014] [proxy:debug] [pid 12217:tid 140330025703168] proxy_util.c(2304): [client 10.1.1.2:52526] AH00947: connected /var/www/html/info.php to localhost:9001
[Sun Jun 15 12:32:30.840272 2014] [authz_core:debug] [pid 12217:tid 140330025703168] mod_authz_core.c(828): [client 10.1.1.2:52526] AH01628: authorization result: granted (no directives)
[Sun Jun 15 12:32:30.842988 2014] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 12217:tid 140330025703168] [client 10.1.1.2:52526] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
[Sun Jun 15 12:32:30.843095 2014] [proxy:debug] [pid 12217:tid 140330025703168] proxy_util.c(2132): AH00943: FCGI: has released connection for (localhost)
[Sun Jun 15 12:32:30.843134 2014] [proxy_balancer:debug] [pid 12217:tid 140330025703168] mod_proxy_balancer.c(670): [client 10.1.1.2:52526] AH01176: proxy_balancer_post_request for (balancer://localhost)
[Sun Jun 15 12:32:30.978315 2014] [authz_core:debug] [pid 12217:tid 140330017310464] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 10.1.1.2:52526] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Sun Jun 15 12:32:30.978346 2014] [authz_core:debug] [pid 12217:tid 140330017310464] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 10.1.1.2:52526] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Sun Jun 15 12:32:30.978387 2014] [core:info] [pid 12217:tid 140330017310464] [client 10.1.1.2:52526] AH00128: File does not exist: /var/www/html/favicon.ico
```

Comment: Have you check here? https://serverfault.com/questions/450628/apache-2-4-php-fpm-proxypassmatch

Answer (score 9):

tcpdump can be helpful in this case.

```
tcpdump port 9001 -A | strings
```

It will show you where apache try to find your primary file

Comment: Thanks that one saved me a couple of hours searching for the obvious :) (my fcgi path was bad :))

Comment: In my case the requests were processed via a non-default interface and not listed, using this fixes that:
`tcpdump port 9001 -A -i any | strings`